# Monit check fails when I add test for status == 0

Tags: unix, monit

I am running M/Monit 5.14 on Debian Jessie. I have a check like this:

```
check program myscript with path "/etc/monit/scripts/test.sh"
  if status != 0 then exec "/etc/monit/scripts/record_failure.sh"
  if status == 0 then exec "/etc/monit/scripts/record_success.sh"
```

The idea is that these `record` scripts will send a record of the result of this test every time it runs. Sure, there are other ways to do this, but this is just a particular route I took in this case. I'm more concerned with the fact that adding the `status == 0` line makes the monit check always fail, even though the last result in `monit status` is `0` and `record_success.sh` is being run.

There's nothing about this documented on [the site](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#PROGRAM-STATUS-TESTING). Is it failing the check because there is a matching condition, or did I mess up the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this is an old post, I just came accross the same issue and it would have been helpful to have a solution.

According to the [Serivce Testing General Syntax](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#GENERAL-SYNTAX) the right structure to check for testing a program should be

```
IF <test> THEN <action> [ELSE IF SUCCEEDED THEN <action>]
```

As you can see, the successful case (0 by convention) should be specified by the `succeeded` keyword.

In this case the following change should make it happy:

```
check program myscript with path "/etc/monit/scripts/test.sh"
    if status != 0 then exec "/etc/monit/scripts/record_failure.sh"
    else if succeeded then exec "/etc/monit/scripts/record_success.sh"
```

Comment: While this does fix the problem of the `monit status` showing the test as failed, the `else if succeeded` block only gets executed when the check goes from failure to success. This was insufficient for my purposes - I ended up having to write a generic wrapper script for every one of my monit tests so I could execute the functionality of the two "record" scripts every time the test was run.

Comment: _Technically_ this answers my original question, though, so I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small test on my side with the following script and your Monit configuration, returning the exit status depending on the last command, and tailing `/var/log/tester.log`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is a test" >> /var/log/tester.log
exit
```

Failure:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "failure in this case" >> /var/log/tester.log
```

Success:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "success in this case" >> /var/log/tester.log
```

While switching from `exit` to `exit 1` , the status was toggling with no issue. `Monit version 5.6`

- I would try to debug the returned status from your script.
- I would check if all those files are executable.

Comment: My scripts returned 0 in both cases, that was probably the trick.

Comment: Okay, got around to testing it. You'll have to clarify how you were switching from `exit` to `exit 1`. Do you mean in your first script, the one that monit runs? I did that and `monit summary` continued to show `Status failed` no matter what the script returned. As I stated in my original question, my check was running the respective success/failure scripts correctly, but the check still showed as failing in `monit summary`. Oh, and yes, all of those files are executable and have shebangs! :)

Comment: Yes, I was switching the status in the script itself, giving it a different exit flag. `exit 1` or `exit 0/exit` , for why it is showing in the log that it is still failing, I dont know to be honest, cant reproduce on my side. version of Monit may be ?

Comment: I reported this as a bug but haven't gotten a response; will update if I get one.